# Mod() function in R equivalent for MatLab?

Tags: r, matlab

I have this code in R:

```
> test <- c(1+1i,2+2i,3+3i,4+4i,5+5i)
> test
[1] 1+1i 2+2i 3+3i 4+4i 5+5i
> Mod(test)
[1] 1.414214 2.828427 4.242641 5.656854 7.071068
```

I cannot find a substitution for the R Mod() function. I tried the real() function in MatLab, but that removes the imaginary component (not want I want).

```
>> test = [1+1*i, 2+2*i, 3+3*i, 4+4*i, 5+5*i]
test =
1.0000 + 1.0000i   2.0000 + 2.0000i   3.0000 + 3.0000i   4.0000 + 4.0000i   5.0000 + 5.0000i
>> real(test)
ans =
1     2     3     4     5
```

Comment: from https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com , sectrion*Magnitude of Complex Number* , maybe`abs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the abs() function in Matlab.

```
y = abs([3+4i,1+i])
>> ans = 5.0000  1.4142
```

Comment: For reference, the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html) for `abs` has a very simple definition "Absolute value and **complex magnitude**" which shows this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [real](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/real.html) and [imag](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/real.html) functions return the respective parts of a complex number. To get the magnitude of a complex number, [abs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html) is used. The `abs` function "returns the absolute value of each element in array X, or if X is complex, abs(X) returns the complex magnitude."